# How to upload file in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to `upload` a picture in `codeigniter` . but I get this error

> unsuccessful=    You did not select a file to upload.

My code:

```
    function uploadImageAvatar(){


        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "/public_html/assets/Vitrin/Avatars/",
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
            'overwrite' => FALSE,
            'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
            'max_height' => "768",
            'max_width' => "1024"
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']))
        {
            echo "successful";

        }
        else
        {

            echo "unsuccessful=".$this->upload->display_errors();
        }
}
```

My html:

```
 <form action="{{base_url().'cp/Users/uploadImageAvatar'}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">

            <input name="image_file" type="file" required="true" />

            <input type="submit" value="upload" id="submit-btn" />
</form>
```

where is i'm wrong ?

Comment: Just change temp name to `$this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['image_file']['name'])`

Comment: but I get the same error .

Comment: try with $this->upload->do_upload('image_file') here is example http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26381226/Codeigniter-File-Uploading-Error.html

Comment: the error message is changed  : `The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

Comment: add 'upload_path' => base_url()."/assets/Vitrin/Avatars/" make sure directory exists

Comment: The error message is enough explain the  problem. Check your path is valid or not aslo check permission of it

Comment: @ Maninderpreet Singh please post your comment as an answer. tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
if($this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']))
```

to

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))
```